# How to return a vector from repository to the service layer

Tags: c++

For the repository i had to use a implementation of a linked list of Movie , ( all is a list ) , but i need to return a vector of the elements from the list to the services layer, I'm kind of lost and I would really need some help

```
const vector <Movie>& MovieRepo::getAll() const noexcept {
    vector<Movie> vect;
    for (auto& m : all) {
        vect.push_back(m);
    }
    return vect;
}
```

Error: Warning  C4172   returning address of local variable or temporary: vect

Comment: `const vector <Movie>&` -> `vector <Movie>`

Comment: or just `return all;`

Comment: @Sopel , it worked with first solution, i can't return all, i have to return a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible fix 1:

```
const vector <Movie> MovieRepo::getAll() const noexcept {
    vector<Movie> vect;
    for (auto& m : all) {
        vect.push_back(m);
    }
    return vect;
}
```

`const vector <Movie>&` means you will return a `const &` to a temporary(`vect`). This temporary will be destroyed after the function returns.

Possible fix 2:

If you want to return a reference:

```
const vector <Movie>& MovieRepo::getAll() const noexcept {
    return all;
}
```